# jQuery setting of radio button using eq fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, `plane.posFile` is a string array of length 3 that identifies 3 radio buttons, and the buttons display correctly.

If `oSource.posfile` is a blank string, the 0th button gets checked correctly.

If `oSource.posfile` is not blank, it is one of the three in `plane.posFile` except that the file extensions have to be stripped for the comparison.

What happens is that the code correctly (using Firebug to step through it) chooses which index to use.

It goes through into the break statement and then out with `i=1`.

However, the attempt to set when `eq(i)` the `attr('checked',true)` files. I don't see why. It's the same statement as previously when `eq(0)` was used. I've been staring at it for a couple of hours trying things with no luck.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, including comments on the approach.

```
$wb.pcPosCfg.empty();
for (i=0; i<plane.posFile.length; i++)
     $wb.pcPosCfg.append("<input type='radio' style='width:11px' name='rbnLoadCfg' value=" + i + ">" + plane.posFile[i] + "<br>");
    if (oSource.posfile=='') {
        $('input[name="rbnLoadCfg"]:eq(0)').attr('checked',true);
    }
    else {
        for (i=0; i<plane.posFile.length; i++) {
            if (oSource.posfile==plane.posFile[i].substring(0,plane.posFile[i].length-5))
                break;
            }
        $('input[name="rbnLoadCfg"]:eq(i)').attr('checked',true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[name="rbnLoadCfg"]:eq('+i+')').attr('checked',true);
```

You need to concatenate your string to include your variable properly.

Comment: It works, but I really don't get why. The jQuery documentation says that what is in the eq() is to be an interger I think. I tried some experimentation. If I put in a number such a 0, 1 or 2, it works. If, however, I use eq("+i+") it doesn't work. I have to use '+i'. What am I concatenating to?

Comment: Correct. An integer is a whole number, so 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. Before, as it was part of a string it tried to enter 'i' - which is not an integer at all, it's a character. We use string concatenation to add strings together, and in this way, we can add in the variable `i`. String concatenation in Javascript is done with `+`. Hope this explains things more slightly.

Comment: @ahred Okay, it finally dawned on me. It got stuck in my mind that eq('+i+') being a function-like call, the '+i+' was it's argument, and that made no sense at all. I just wasn't connecting the dots to realize it was to be inside a string being passed to jQuery. Thanks again.